# How to disable private browsing on iPad, iOS 9?

Tags: ios, ipad

We have an iPad that we use as our POS at work.  I want to disable the private browsing function to be able to make sure people are not browsing the web.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could possibly Jailbreak it and remove the feature. Or have a read [Here](http://ipadtutr.com/private-browsing-button-missing-safari/) This may help you out a bit.

Comment: Your real problem is stopping people from using the web, not from using private browsing. Unless you have another reason that wasn't included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure people are not browsing the web, *disable the web*. That is, set up a proxy server that blocks access to external websites – Squid or Privoxy would work – and configure the iPad to use that proxy server for everything. Then block direct connections (without a proxy) in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily block web browsing or *limit it* with pretty much any of the newer routers on the market today.  I prefer limiting becuase while you may want to block general surfing, you may still need to get access to whatever cloud services your POS or business might need access to.

For example, Linksys has a feature called "Parental Controls" that allows you to lock down particular devices or IPs.

[image]

That's just Linksys' version. Pretty much all new routers have this feature built in.  Generally speaking,  you would want to limit access to the web by blocking all sites and allowing only a few during the times you specify.

The best part is, if you already have a newer router, you don't have to spend any additional time or money coming up with a solution - you already own it.